# Is there a "serverless" solution for a (gaming) server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, serverless

I am working on a game atm and started to research about an alternative solution to dedicated servers.
The reason I am doing this is that I have little administration knowledge and would prefer to spend the time in programming instead of learning that. Especially when it comes to security to the dedicated machine itself and not my application that runs on it.

So my question is whether there is a possibility of a server where you can just run your code written e.g. in golang and have less or easier administration and a much better or the same security?
It would be perfect if I just get an endpoint connection to my application when a client wants to communicate without the care of security concerns outside of my application.

I have looked on some services from aws and google (not tested for now) but with the whole range everything is confusing to me.

Information about the type of game:

- realtime multiplayer
- for now I use TCP with Flatbuffer to communicate (TCP should be also fine here)
- server is written in golang and for the client for testing I use libgdx (java), but would probably change to something else when I solved other questions
- with server I mean where the logic is run server-side and the communication between the client to the database is made through the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to avoid maintaining a server for your software, consider dockerizing your server software, and run it on AWS Fargate. It will not necessarily be cheaper than a dedicated server, but you will not have to maintain any infrastructure or OS.

Answer (score -1):

Short anwser, no.

Serverless architectures doesn't work well with TCP, because of various reasons. The First one to be that FaaS is made to be short lived - opening a TCP connection with sockets would create a long live for the function, thus making its costs go high.
Second, BaaS usually has a delay of some microseconds, and also doesn't support TCP connections.
But you see, with BaaS you can develop a turn-based multiplayer game, because the delay isn't that critical on these types of applications.